# PHP tinymce, validation issue

Tags: php, tinymce, sugarcrm

I'm using tinymce on my CMS page and facing a issue for require validation (jquery). Everything goes well but when I'm inserting only date{DATE d/m/Y} using editor. jquery validation do not goes off.

I mean if only date is there it creates a problem if I give white space after or before that validation works well. But why validation don't work when only Date{DATE d/m/Y} is there ??

What should I do to resolve this ?

```
tinyMCE.init({
                theme : "advanced",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                height : "400px",
                mode: "exact",
                elements : "description",
                plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,ibrowser",
                setup : function(ed){

                ed.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, event) {
                        tinymce.triggerSave();
                        $("#EditView#description").trigger({type: 'keyup', ctrlKey: event.ctrlKey, altKey: event.altKey, which: event.keyCode, event:eventObject });
                });
            },

                theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen,ibrowser",
                theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage", 
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                width: "100%",
                inline_styles : true,
                directionality : "ltr",
                entity_encoding: 'raw',
                cleanup_on_startup : true,
                strict_loading_mode : true,
                convert_urls : false,
                remove_redundant_brs : true,
                plugin_insertdate_dateFormat : '{DATE '+df+'}',
                content_css :cssurl+"/includes/style/style.css",
        });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? check in firebug

Comment: @LearneR: No there is no error.

Comment: And it is not just about date. If I add some table and left them blank. It gives same result

Comment: Please post you tinyMCE initialization js code

Comment: How are you getting the value of textarea for validation?

Comment: addToValidate('EditView', 'description', 'text', true,'Description' );

its a sugarCRM's function that add this field automatically to validation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your validation mechanism doesn't take into account that tinymce is not equal the textarea or input field you have in your form. But tinymce creates a new iframe in which the editor content gets edited.